# My functions for a vector don't seem to be working? C++ (adding or deleting an item, displaying a vector)

Tags: string, function, vector, iterator, c++-cli

I'm doing an exercise from my textbook that has me create a program that allows the user to manage a list of favorite games by adding, deleting, or viewing the items in the vector. I made use of functions; my program runs, but the functions don't seem to be doing what they're supposed to. I'm able to input a game name for addGame(), but when I input 4 in the do/while loop, no vector is printed. Likewise, the removeGame() function doesn't seem to be working since it displays no message if I type in a game not in the list.

Which function is at fault for the lack of display? Both or just one (addGame or dispGames)? And why is my removeGame function not working?

Thanks for helping.

```
// exercises ch 4.cpp : main project file.

#include "stdafx.h"
#include<iostream>
#include<string>
#include<vector>
#include<iterator>

using namespace std;

void addGame(vector<string> faveGames);
void removeGame(vector<string> faveGames);
void dispGames(vector<string> faveGames);



int main(array<System::String ^> ^args)
{
vector<string> faveGames;
int choice;

cout << "Welcome to the Favorite Games List program!\n\n";

do
{

    cout << "What would you like to do?\n\n";
    cout << "1 - End program. \n 2 - Add new game to list. \n 3 - Remove game from list. \n 4 - Display list. \n";
    cout << "Enter the corresponding number of your choice: ";
    cin >> choice;
switch (choice)
{
case 1: cout << "Ending program.\n"; break;
case 2: addGame(faveGames) ; break;
case 3: removeGame(faveGames); break;
case 4: dispGames(faveGames); break;
default: "That is not a valid response, please try again.";
}
}
while(choice != 1);

return 0;

}

void addGame(vector<string> faveGames) {

string newFaveGame;
cout << "Enter the name of the game you want to add: ";
cin >> newFaveGame;
faveGames.push_back(newFaveGame);

}

void removeGame(vector<string> faveGames) {

vector<string>::iterator deletedGameIter;
string deletedGame;

cout << "Enter the name of the game you want to delete: ";
cin >> deletedGame;

for(deletedGameIter = faveGames.begin(); deletedGameIter != faveGames.end(); ++deletedGameIter) {

if(deletedGame == *deletedGameIter) {
    faveGames.erase(deletedGameIter);
}
else
{
    cout << "That game is not on your list.\n";
}
}

}

void dispGames(vector<string> faveGames) {

vector<string>::iterator iter;
for(iter = faveGames.begin(); iter != faveGames.end(); ++iter)
{
    cout << *iter << endl;
}

}
```

Comment: You should be using `deletedGameIter->compare(deletedGame) == 0` Not your problem but some fun advice.

Comment: Send the vectors by reference in your functions, you are now sending them by value, so probably you are not modifying anything.

Comment: @Ben, No, not with `std::string`. That just makes it harder to read.

Comment: This isn't even C++. It's either C++/CLI or C++/CX, please re-tag the question correctly.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Main problem:

You are passing `faveGames` by value. Any changes to `faveGames` don't change the variable in `main`.

You need to pass them by reference if you want the changes to be visible in `main`:

```
void addGame(vector<string>& faveGames);
void removeGame(vector<string>& faveGames);
```

There are other problems in your code that need to be cleaned up too.

**Problem**

You have

```
int main(array<System::String ^> ^args)
```

This is not standard C++ code. Are you using Microsoft Managed C++?

**Problem**

You have

```
faveGames.erase(deletedGameIter);
```

in `removeGame`. At that point, `deletedGameIter` is an invalid object. Incrementing it will lead to undefined behavior. You can change the for loop in that function to:

```
for(deletedGameIter = faveGames.begin();
    deletedGameIter != faveGames.end();
     ++deletedGameIter) {

   if(deletedGame == *deletedGameIter) {
       faveGames.erase(deletedGameIter);
       return
   }
}
```

if you don't expect to see the game multiple times in the your list. If you expect to see it multiple times, you can use:

```
for(deletedGameIter = faveGames.begin();
    deletedGameIter != faveGames.end(); ) {

   if(deletedGame == *deletedGameIter) {
       deletedGameIter = faveGames.erase(deletedGameIter);
   }
   else {
      ++deletedGameIter;
   }
}
```

Comment: Oh man I remember learning about that. Duh! Thanks a lot! I really appreciate it.

Comment: @izaheichou: unless your vectors are huge, pass them by value into a function, return the new vector from the function, and in main assign the return value to faveGames.

Comment: @eswarp25 Why? Care to add a reason?

Comment: @Praetorian It just makes debugging and testing easier. You can just test a function individually.

Comment: @eswarp25, And you can't with passing by reference?

Comment: @eswarp25 ok, but what does passing them in by value have to do with that? You can keep the function behavior the same by passing them in  by `const&`

Comment: @Praetorian const& would work if he was not modifying the vector inside his functions. But he is adding or deleting elements from vector.

Comment: @chris pass by reference (without const) is bad when you are in a multi-threaded environment. It can easily introduce so many bugs. For small cases, passing by reference or value probably does not matter, but it makes a huge difference in concurrent programming

Comment: Yea, I guess, since I'm using Visual Studio Express 2010. It was kinda just there, so I left it. I don't really know what it's for. And yea, I noticed it would print "That game is not on your list" until it reached the game name that was entered. I was trying to fix that just now. Thanks

Comment: @eswarp25, Okay, yes, pure functions are useful for concurrent programs. The OP's code is nowhere near concurrent, though.